# Retrieve Error Logs for Task Failure within Apache Airflow with STABLE REST API

Tags: python, rest, airflow

Creating a script to ease the way of reading Apache Airflow data, I was able to retrieve failed tasks and other data, but could not find a way to get errors logs for the task that failed.

I looked through the docs for any possible endpoints that could help. Looking to get something back like this:

> raise AirflowException(
> airflow.exceptions.AirflowException: Bash command failed. The command returned a non-zero exit code 1.
> During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:
> Traceback (most recent call last):

When I request logs I usually get a overview of what was done to the DAG.

https://airflow.apache.org/docs/apache-airflow/stable/stable-rest-api-ref.html#tag/Role